# How to reverse the actions of the od command?

Tags: bash, shell, task, reverse-engineering

How can you reverse the actions of this command:
`od -A n -t x1`
I found only command `xxd -r` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: The command you show doesn’t do anything because there is no input file specified. And even if you did specify one, its content would not be affected so there’s not really anything that needs undoing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `od` and `xxd` can operate on standard input (as can most similar utilities), so it seems reasonable to assume that is how they are being used here. I have made this assumption in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Question: **How can you reverse the actions of this command: `od -A n -t x1`**

Answer: **You can’t.**

The command you gave removes duplicate lines. To reverse the command, you would need to put those duplicate lines back, which requires you to know how many times each line was duplicated. But the command you gave also removes that information.

If we assume that there are no duplicate lines (or if you retain them by adding `-v` to `od`), then you can use `xxd -p -r`.

Note that `xxd -r` is designed to reverse **the output of `xxd`**. It is not designed to reverse the output of any other program, including `od`. However, at least in my tests, it can cope with the spaces in `od -A n -t x1`’s output.

---

**Edit:** The following paragraphs are to clarify what I wrote above.

`xxd -r` is designed to reverse the output of `xxd`. Your starting point in solving this problem should be to run `xxd` and compare its output to the output of `od` or `od -A n -t x1`. It turns out that the output of `xxd` is very different to the output of either `od` or `od -A n -t x1`, so we expect `xxd -r` to fail.

The next thing you should look at is whether you can pass `xxd` some extra parameters to make its output look more like the output of `od`; you can then add the same parameters to `xxd -r` (only works for some parameters). For example, you can reverse the output of `xxd -p` using `xxd -p -r`. Does the output of `xxd -p` look more similar to the output of `od -A n -t x1`? Yes. In fact, the outputs are identical except for `od` using different line lengths and adding spaces.

Now making the outputs actually identical is a slightly harder problem. But, at least according to my tests, you don’t have to. You can simply pass the output of `od -A -n -t x1` directly to `xxd -p -r`.

If you want to make the outputs actually identical, you should be able to do it using the `-w` parameter to `od` and piping the output through `sed s/ //g`.